# A program to 'listen' for a particular audio frequency then run a task

Tags: windows, audio, automation

I need a program (for Windows) that continually 'listens' to a computers own audio ('what you hear' type, preferably).

Now, once it's 'heard' a set frequency it runs 'batch01.bat', at another set frequency it runs 'batch02.bat' etc.

The reason behind this is to play sounds on the PC that the computer will then react to.

Is this possible? I've been searching the web for a simple code/program but they all output to a graph or something.

My programming skills are limited to HTML and batch files, so please go easy on me :)

Comment: What price range? What OS (ie Windows as unor suggests)?

Comment: Sorry guys, yup, I'm on windows. Something that runs on W7 64bit preferably? Price range? As cheap as possible, really.

Comment: Take a look at Girder http://www.promixis.com/

Answer (score 2):

## [Remote.js](https://github.com/hacksparrow/remote.js)

Remote.js is a library for developing remote controlled web apps. It is wireless and does not require additional hardware - it works via audio frequencies.

Github: https://github.com/hacksparrow/remote.js

---

This obviously requires further work from your side (some local php file + server to execute the batch files) but since you already know HTML this might be one of the easiest solutions. It is to say though that depending on what you are doing this solution might not be as stable as you want it to be.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful, I'll take a closer look at it.